# Using constants (variables) in bash

Tags: bash

I have the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -eux

# Go Home.
cd /vagrant/Freya/

CLEANED_ASSETS=false

## Clean up time!
## Remove all vendor and composer.lock folders - just because.
for f in *; do
  if [[ -d $f ]]; then
    if [[ $f != ".git" ]] && [[ $f != "bin" ]] && [[ $f != "docs" ]]; then

      if [[ $f == "Loader"]] && CLEANED_ASSETS == false; then
        if [[ -d "Assets"]]; then
          cd Assets/
          rm -rf vendor composer.lock
          CLEANED_ASSETS = true
          cd ../../
        fi
      fi

      cd "$f/"
      rm -rf vendor composer.lock
      cd ../
    fi
  fi
done
```

Which basically fails the check at line 16: `if [[ $f == "Loader"]] && CLEANED_ASSETS == false; then` by throwing the following error:

```
$ bin/clean-directories
+ cd /vagrant/Freya/
+ CLEANED_ASSETS=false
bin/clean-directories: line 16: syntax error in conditional expression: unexpected token `;'
```

And I am not sure why. **Any ideas?**

Comment: To reference the value contained in `CLEANED_ASSETS` you have to prefix the name with `$`. Also enclose the value inside double quotes: `"$CLEANED_ASSETS" == "false"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
if [[ $f == "Loader" ]] && [[ $CLEANED_ASSETS == "false" ]]; then
```

instead

Comment: This solves one problem, but not another: you need a space before the `]]` that closes a conditional expression.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems here, mostly involving incorrect spacing. First, in a conditional expression (i.e. `[[ ... ]]`), spaces are *required* between all elements -- after the `[[`, between the operands and operators, and before the `]]`. Thus `[[ $f == "Loader"]]` needs to be replaced by `[[ $f == "Loader" ]]` and `[[ -d "Assets"]]` needs to be `[[ -d "Assets" ]]`. Second, spaces *cannot* be used around the `=` in an assignment, so `CLEANED_ASSETS = true` must be replaced by `CLEANED_ASSETS=true`. Third, `CLEANED_ASSETS == false` isn't a comparison; you need to write it as `[[ $CLEANED_ASSETS == false ]]`.

(BTW, you can use [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net) to check for syntax errors like these.)

Finally, I think there's a problem with the `cd` sequence in the innermost `if` -- you do `cd Assets/`, followed by `cd ../../`, which will leave you one directory level up from where you started. I generally recommend avoiding `cd` in scripts unless it's really necessary, because it's really easy to create bugs like this. In this case, I'd just skip all but the first `cd` and use `rm -rf Assets/vendor Assets/composer.lock` and then later `rm -rf "$f/vendor" "$f/composer.lock"`.